# Getting Original Path from FileStream

Tags: c#, path, filestream, .net

Given a `System.IO.FileStream` object, how can I get the original path to the file it's providing access to?

For example, in the `MyStreamHandler()` function below, I want to get back the path of the file that created the `FileStream`:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
    FileStream fs = File.Create(path));

    MyStreamHandler(fs);
    MyOtherStreamHandler(fs);

    fs.Close();
    fs.Dispose();
}

private static void MyStreamHandler(FileStream fs)
{
    // Get the originating path of 'fs'
} 

private static void MyOtherStreamHandler(FileStream fs)
{
}
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The FileStream's Name property.

See documentation in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.name(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answering what was apparently an RTFM-type question. I did actually, but it wasn't obvious to me that Name got the path.

Comment: I hate to say it, but why read the manual when you have StackOverflow? It's sooo much faster to find, with examples by people that use the technology.

Comment: @AdrianCarr because the manual has example whilst the answer not 

Comment: FYI: If the absolute path is not known, this property returns a string similar to "[Unknown]". It's the case when FileStream was instantiated using SafeFileHandle.

Answer (score 7):

You can use fs.Name to get the path.

Answer (score 1):

Use FileInfo-Class for getting the path.

```
var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

Settings.Default.ThePath = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
Settings.Default.Save();
```